# Start hangouts from my app?

Tags: android, google-hangouts

I want to start `Hangouts` from within my android app, but I could not find anything to accomplish this.

Is there any API or library available which can be used to start the hangouts, just like starting the gallery / camera intents ?

Please Help. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Ok, I found that by doing this we can join the hangouts from another android app.

`Intent sky = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/UNIQUE_HANGOUT_ID"));
startActivity(sky);`

But, it can only **Join** previously created hangouts. Is there any way that we can create new hangout from a process similar to this one.

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: How do you get the "UNIQUE_HANGOUT_ID" ? Also, have you tried this: https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/3k5hk3/anyone_know_how_to_open_a_hangouts_conversation/cuwg687 ?

Answer (score 0):

hello u can use the [Google+ Hangouts](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started) API to implement the hangouts with in your application
for further information use [link](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started#simple)

Comment: Is this response/answer correct? I believe these links are for a javascript based solution in browsers. 
The question regards a solution using Android Java & intents.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of apps in the Play Store that allow you to inspect the intents that an application is capable of receiving. For example, [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective) let's you view the manifest (and thus the registered intent handlers) of the apps installed on your system and [Intent Intercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) allows you to inspect the contents of broadcastd intents. You could use this to reverse engineer a solution ([as was done on this hread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/50lszUsTKmc)). However, relying on undocumented internal behavior may result in you getting broken at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me to open Hangout from my application.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intentInv.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.talk", "com.google.android.apps.hangouts.phone.BabelHomeActivity"));
        intentInv.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intentInv);
```

(or)

```
        Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.talk");
        startActivity(i);
```